# ApiGateway CloudFormation without lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create a template so that when i call `api/divide/inputvalue`, The api sends back response from `DynamoDB` which corresponds to `inputvalue` mapping.

Its pretty straight forward since i am fetching value directly from db without any business logic hence I don't need any lambda. But all the examples that I google or all tutorials they are using lambdas and i am now lost that how can i make it working without lambda

This is what I have so far. There is bug in this template right now since I haven't provided `Uri` in `ApiGateway::Method`. Which is what I am currently stuck at.

```
{

  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Resources": {
    "Deployment": {
      "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment",
      "Properties": {
        "RestApiId": { "Ref": "restApiName" },
        "Description": "First Deployment",
        "StageName": "StagingStage"
      },
      "DependsOn" : ["restApiMethod"]
    },
    "restApiMethod": {
      "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::Method",
      "Properties": {
        "AuthorizationType": "NONE",
        "HttpMethod": "GET",
        "ResourceId": {"Ref": "apiRestResource"},
        "RestApiId": {"Ref": "restApiName"},
        "Integration": {
          "Type": "AWS",
          "IntegrationHttpMethod": "GET",
          "IntegrationResponses": [{"StatusCode": 200}],
          "Uri": { "Fn::Sub":"arn.aws.apigateway:${AWS::Region}:dynamodb:action/${restApiName.Arn}"}
        },
        "MethodResponses": [{"StatusCode": 200}]
      },
      "DependsOn": ["apiRestResource"]
    },
    "apiRestResource": {
      "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::Resource",
      "Properties": {
        "RestApiId": {"Ref": "restApiName"},
        "ParentId": {
          "Fn::GetAtt": ["restApiName","RootResourceId"]
        },
        "PathPart": "divide"
      },
      "DependsOn": ["restApiName"]
    },
    "restApiName": {
      "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi",
      "Properties": {
        "Name": "CalculationApi"
      }
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, the [`Uri`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-apitgateway-method-integration.html#cfn-apigateway-method-integration-uri) property is structured as follows for `AWS` service-proxy integration types:

> If you specify `AWS` for the `Type` property, specify an AWS service that follows the form: `arn:aws:apigateway:region:subdomain.service|service:path|action/service_api`. For example, a Lambda function URI follows the form: `arn:aws:apigateway:region:lambda:path/path`. The path is usually in the form `/2015-03-31/functions/LambdaFunctionARN/invocations`. For more information, see the [`uri`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/resource/integration/#uri) property of the [Integration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/resource/integration/) resource in the Amazon API Gateway REST API Reference.

The [`uri`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/resource/integration/#uri) API Gateway property reference provides more details:

> For AWS integrations, the URI should be of the form `arn:aws:apigateway:{region}:{subdomain.service|service}:{path|action}/{service_api}`. `Region`, `subdomain` and `service` are used to determine the right endpoint. For AWS services that use the `Action=` query string parameter, `service_api` should be a valid action for the desired service. For RESTful AWS service APIs, `path` is used to indicate that the remaining substring in the URI should be treated as the path to the resource, including the initial `/`.

For an AWS service proxy to the `dynamodb` service calling the [`Query`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html) [Action](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Operations.html), the `Uri` should be something like this (using the YAML short-form of [`Fn::Sub`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html) to insert a [`Ref`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-ref.html) for the current AWS region):

```
!Sub "arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:dynamodb:action/Query"
```

As for your broader use-case of using API Gateway to access DynamoDB without using Lambda functions, refer to Andrew Baird's tutorial blog post, ["Using Amazon API Gateway as a Proxy for DynamoDB"](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-api-gateway-as-a-proxy-for-dynamodb/), and translate the specified Management Console steps to corresponding CloudFormation template resources.

Comment: Thanks. That was helpful. I was already looking at service url when i saw your reply. I have updated the *template*. Now the part i am stuck at is to get the path parameter in my case `inputvalue` from url `api/divide/inputvalue` and use it dynamodb query. I was looking at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-method.html#d0e33813 example to see how can i do so but the resulting template gave me error that `resource attribute restApiName.Arn` is invalid.

Comment: You should be able to define "RequestParameters" in restApiMethod and refer to that in the integration request template.