# Invalid ARN when creating an integration for AWS::ApiGateway::Method via CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

I have built out an API Gateway that integrates with Dynamodb using the AWS Console and have it up and running as a proof of concept. Now I want to take that API Gateway and re-produce it via CloudFormation for actual usage.

I've been able to get most of it deployed using my CFT but I'm stuck on the `AWS::ApiGateway::Method` resource. Specifically, the `Integration` property.

```
  ResourceHttpGet:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
    Properties:
      AuthorizationScopes:
        - openid
      AuthorizationType: COGNITO_USER_POOLS
      AuthorizerId: {'Fn::ImportValue': !Sub '${ProductName}-${TargetEnvironment}-authorizer-customerpool' }
      HttpMethod: GET
      OperationName: GetFoo
      RequestModels:
        "application/json": {'Fn::ImportValue': !Sub '${ProductName}-${TargetEnvironment}-apigw-foomodel' }
      Integration: 
        Credentials: !Ref ApiGatewayDynamoDbRole
        IntegrationHttpMethod: POST
        RequestTemplates:
         application/json: !Sub '{ "TableName": "${ProductName}-${TargetEnvironment}-dynamo-primaryapi", "KeyConditionExpression": "UserId = :val", "Limit": 50, "ExpressionAttributeValues": { ":val": { "S": "$context.authorizer.claims.sub" } } }'
        Type: AWS
        Uri: !Sub "arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:dynamodb:action/Query"
      ResourceId: !Ref FooResource
      RestApiId: {'Fn::ImportValue': !Sub '${ProductName}-${TargetEnvironment}-apigw-primaryapi' }
```

When I upload this into the CloudFormation Console and run it the CF Stack fails with the following error on the `ResourceHttpGet` resource:

> Invalid ARN specified in the request (Service: AmazonApiGateway; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadRequestException; Request ID: e6767c61-96dc-461a-ab7c-fd625344b59f; Proxy: null)

I can comment out the `Integration` property and the Stack successfully deploys. I've used a couple of different resources to help validate the ARN I'm using is accurate. One being [a blog post I found](https://itnext.io/setting-up-api-gateway-with-dynamodb-using-cloudformation-a8ab3e70f494) on API Gateway/Dynamodb integration and [a second being here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42011362/apigateway-cloudformation-without-lambda) on Stackoverflow

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong here? Why doesn't it like the Uri I provide when it confirms to the [specification/API requirements](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-apitgateway-method-integration.html) below:

> arn:aws:apigateway:region:subdomain.service|service:path|action/service_api. For example, a Lambda function URI follows this form: arn:aws:apigateway:region:lambda:path/path.

I've also removed the `!sub` function usage and just hard-coded the Region into the Uri in order to test if the usage of intrinsic functions caused the issue but that didn't make a difference.

Totally confused and would appreciate any guidance someone can give to me on this.

Comment: Can you make it work in AWS Console? If it works there, you could then inspect what is the actual form of the URI that the console setups.

Comment: I tried to use the template designer tool to create this specific resource in the Console but could not figure it out. When I dragged the resource onto the designer there weren't any properties for me to enter. When I check the API Gateway Console for the working Gateway the Request Integration doesn't provide me with the Uri/Arn. It just lists the service I've integrated with as DynamoDb.

Comment: Your uri looks fine. What exactly is `ApiGatewayDynamoDbRole`, because the error does not specify that uri is only suspect. Maybe your `credentails` have wrong ARN?

Comment: I actually tested that - created a DynamoDB Table in the template itself and referenced it via `!GetAtt MyTable.Arn` but it still failed with the same error. Doesn't appear to be the IAM Role.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to create a CloudFormation file based on an API Gateway setup that you've created manually, I would take a look at [AWS SAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/what-is-sam.html). Which is much less verbose and easier to set up. Specifically, I would have a look at the `DefinitionBody` property of the `AWS::Serverless::Api` type. This property allows you to pass in an openapi body definition of your API.

As a starting point, you can also [export your current api](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-export-api.html) using the console or one of the other methods indicated in the documentation.

Combining those two things would make it a lot easier to construct your API Gateway in CloudFormation.